# Selenium (WebDriver) cannot see richfaces modal panel

Tags: testing, jsf, selenium, richfaces, webdriver

I'm having some issues trying to test elements inside a RichFaces modal panel, as the one
in the demo page of RichFaces [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf?c=modalPanel#)

the issue is that once retrieved an element I cannot interact with it because WebDriver throws a ElementNotVisibleException.

I check it with firebug, and it appears greyed out, because some of the divs have height and width set to 0.

I tried to set all the divs manually with a height and size to see if it changes but there is no way to make it work, so I suppose there must be something else affecting the visibility of the modal panel, but cannot find what.

Has anyone tested webdriver or selenium against a richfaces panel?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
For the code, is too much to put here, but basically I adapted the jbehave tutorial for the etsy website (the one using spring to inject dependencies), that can be found [here](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial/tree/master/etsy-stories-java-spring).

The architecture is using a PropertyWebDriverProvider that is configured by maven properties to use InternetExplorer or Firefox and is using PageObject pattern (all the pages extend from WebDriverPage).

For specific code, the one from JimEvans gives me the same error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide test code that demonstrates the problem you're having. Can you do so against the demo page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found out was to do all the interaction with javascript through webdriver

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work for me using the demo site you linked to in your question. It gets the text content of the modal panel, then clicks the "button" to close the panel.

```
public void testPanel() {
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf?c=modalPanel");
  WebElement panelShow = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id352:link"));
  panelShow.click();
  WebElement panel = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id352:panelCDiv"));
  WebElement panelTextElement = panel.findElement(By.className("rich-mpnl-body"));
  System.out.println(panelTextElement.getText());
  WebElement panelCloseButton = panel.findElement(By.id("j_id352:hidelink"));
  panelCloseButton.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Basically this is what I was doing, but just in case I tried copy & paste, and is still not working. Still getting the ElementNonVisibleException. Only difference with your code is that I'm using a PropertyWebDriverProvider to be able to use both InternetExplorer and Firefox, but the driver that I retrieve is InternetExplorer. I will add some more info on the question

Comment: An important piece to note is where you're actually getting the ElementNotFoundException. I had some issues with ElementNotFoundException when getting the link to click on to make the modal panel display, until I got the ID correct for that element. Am I understanding you correctly, that the above code does not work in your environment?

Comment: Exactly, copied everything but the first line, I retrieve the driver from my page, which is a subclass of WebDriverPage, using the webDriver() method

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstand, I get the exception when doing panelCloseButton.click(); I can find the elements and retrieve information from them, the problem is performing any action with them.